# How to solve parameter representation such as $x_1(\tau),x_2(\tau)$ for $x_2^2=x_1^2+x_1^3$.

Tags: calculus

"[Problems And Solutions In Differential Geometry, Lie Series, Differential Forms, Relativity And Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076Z6WWQG)"  by Willi-Hans Steeb Page 3 Section 1.2 Question 1 sub question i.

Related information could be found here: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ParametricEqn.aspx[image]

Solve parameter representation $x_1(\tau),x_2(\tau)$ for $x_2^2=x_1^2+x_1^3$.

The answer was $x_1(\tau)=\tau^2-1,x_2(\tau)=\tau(\tau^2-1)$.

However, I wasn't sure how to derive the answer formally, or how to prove the uniqueness(up to change of variables).

The solution seemed to indicate Lagrangian multiplier with series expansion, but it doesn't appear to be straight forward.

Comment: Please do not repost a question which was earlier deleted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3576602/solve-parameter-representation-x-1-tau-x-2-tau-for-x-22-x-12x-13.  That is equivalent to trying to "game the system."

Comment: And please do not post images when you are perfectly capable of posting the transcribed content of the image in mathjax.

Comment: @amWhy I don't understand what you are trying to get at, I got a proper question and it fits the guidelines. The last was closed for lack of clearity so I posted the entire question.

Comment: No, this remains a poor question which is merely fishing for a complete solution, like your closed and deleted post asking the same thing.  Your job, when a post is closed, is to improve ***it***.  Not to repost essentially the same question, like you did here.  Also, what you copied and pasted is not in any sense, a question.  It is a series of imperatives (orders to find... to solve ... like your post... Do this for me).  This is a question and answer site, not a "do my exercises for me" site.

Comment: @amWhy like I said, it was closed for clearity, so I literally put the entire question there includes all the context. You deleted last one without any comments. How am I supposed to know what you specifically want? And I adjusted the question per posts you provided in the chat.

Comment: "Lacks clarity and details" is the default close reason for "do this for me" posts, where it is clear the OP is simply seeking an answer, with virtually no contributed effort.  I see that here, too.

Comment: And you lie when you say ***I*** deleted your last question.  In fact three users voted to delete the question, after it was closed by five users.  I've flagged this post, for moderator attention, indicating that this is reposted from a post already closed and deleted.

Comment: @amWhy I listed the way I tired in the post, from lagrangian to Taylor series. plus the official answer was included in the post as well. What more do you want? Answer it by myself? I'm not the author.

Comment: @amWhy I mean if you think it's foolish, could you at least put down why you think it's so simple? If you don't have the answer, please let others to answer it. Everyone had the moment when they could use a little bit help. Isn't what's this website for?

Comment: "The solution seemed to indicate Lagrangian multiplier with series expansion, but it doesn't appear to be straight forward."  Does not give us any indication of what you "tired".  Official answers are easily copied and pasted from solution manuals.  There is no effort exhibited here.  Only an expectation that someone "answer this for you."

Comment: @amWhy that's what I tired, it's not standard textbook question that I could recall. It's neither undergraduate calculus or optimization. and you have seen what the online resources about parameter equations looks like.  It's in the post as well. Not quite helpful.

Comment: I don't see any work in your post showing your efforts to try Lagrangian multiplier with series expansion.  Perhaps if you add your efforts in that respect, the post can be salvaged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is one of those outline books with no discussion be fore the problems, just worked solutions. There is not generally any "best" parametization. For a curve in the plane that possesses a self-intersection, we parametrize by slope of lines around that point. Otherwise, try thr same thing, but go around a point so that there is just one addition intersection on each line.

So, $y^2 = x^2 + x^3.$ This is an elliptic curve with self intersection at the origin. We begin with $x = t, y = mt$ which is a line through the origin. The other intersection point come from $$m^2 t^2 = t^2 + t^3. $$ We declare $t \neq 0$ to get
$m^2 = 1 + t$ or $t = m^2 - 1.$  Thus $x=m^2 - 1, \; \; y = m(m^2 -1 ).$

For the unit circle, no self intersection, project around $(-1,0)$ so
$$ x = t - 1 \; , \; \;  y = mt $$
From $t^2 - 2t + 1 + m^2 t^2 = 1$ we reach
$$ t = \frac{2}{m^2 + 1} $$ or
$$  x = \frac{1 - m^2}{1 + m^2} \; \; ,  y = \frac{2m}{1+m^2}  $$
This is the Weierstrass half angle substitution.

In the last, we use the origin   in $y^2 = x^2 - x^4.$ Note that $|x| \leq 1$ We begin with $x=t, y=mt.$ Next $$ m^2 t^2 = t^2 - t^4.  $$ Demanding $t \neq 0$ we find
$m^2 = 1 - t^2,$   or $t^2 = 1 - m^2.$ There is the misfortune that we might need to introduce square roots. To keep everything smooth, we switch to $t = \cos w,$ allowing us to take $m = \sin w.$ Which leas to
$$ x = \cos w \; , \; \;  y = \sin w \cos w $$
I think the book may have chosen the trig functions in the other order.

==========================

Added: we are able to cut down to a single "slope" parameter in the plane. We could have used the better behaved $$ x = x_0 + t m, \;\; y = y_0 + t n   $$ If I am investigating rational points in a surface in $\mathbb R^3,$ usually it is $$ x = x_0 + t p, \;\; y = y_0 + t q, \; \; z = z_0 + t r. $$ Here I demand that $p,q,r$ be integers with $\gcd(p,q,r) = 1.$  The general name for this is stereographic projection.

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense. I got stuck with the ideal of solving constrains. So "parametrize by slope of lines around that point" meant 1. finding zeros in the polynomial 2. make a linear approximation around that point?